# How slow is the LIKE query on MySQL? (Custom fields related)

Tags: mysql, custom-fields

Apologies if this is redundant, and it probably is, I gave it a look but couldn't find a question here that fell in with what I wanted to know.

Basically we have a table with about ~50000 rows, and it's expected to grow much bigger than that. We need to be able to allow admin users to add in custom data to an item based on its category, and users can just pick which fields defined by the administrators they want to add info to.

Initially I had gone with an item_categories_fields table which pairs up entries from item_fields to item_categories, so admins can add custom fields and reuse them across categories for consistency. item_fields has a relationship to item_field_values which links values with fields, which is how we handled things in .NET. The project is using CAKEPHP though, and we're just learning as we go, so it can get a bit annoying at times.

I'm however thinking of maybe just adding an item_custom_fields table that is essentially the item_id and a text field that stores XMLish formatted data. This is just for the values of the custom fields.

No problems if I want to fetch the item by its id as the required data is stored in the items table, but what if I wanted to do a search based on a custom field? Would a

```
SELECT * FROM item_custom_fields 
WHERE custom_data LIKE '%<material>Plastic</material>%'
```

(user input related issues aside) be practical if I wanted to fetch items made of plastic in this case? Like how slow would that be?

Thanks.

Edit: I was afraid of that as realistically this thing will be around 400k rows for that one table at launch, thanks guys.

Comment: It can get very slow. How slow depends on your hardware, software, size of table, length of field... The initial structure you suggested would work a lot faster than a text field.

Comment: take a look of Sphinx search engine

Comment: As icky as some make them out to be, EAV models for "auxiliary user extendible data" can be a viable option as can the more complicated dynamic columns and meta-data mapping approach (i.e. SharePoint). Of course, if this was SQL Server then shredded XML would not be a problem .. but it isn't.

Comment: Have you considered using [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `LIKE` query that starts with `%` will not use any indexes you have on the column, so the query will *scan the whole table* to find the result.

The response time for that depends highly on your machine and the size of the table, but it definitely won't be efficient in any shape or form.

Your previous/existing solution (if well indexed) should be quite a bit faster.